# Deleting objects from GCS using airflow matching a pattern

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to delete the objects from my buckets with certain pattern. but it seems like it is not working as expected. any help will be appriciated

```
delete_data = GCSDeleteObjectsOperator(
    bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME,
    task_id=f"delete_data",
    objects=['test_delete/*/*/*/alpha/data-1-2123-*.json']
)
```

Airflow will always throw an error with the 404 object not found. I can confirm there are objects in the buckets in this pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use **GCSHook** to get the objects on your desired bucket and then filter the objects based on your pattern using *REGEX*.

You may refer to below sample code that I used in my testing:

```py
import datetime

import airflow
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs import GCSHook
from airflow.operators import python

import re

bucket_name = 'your-bucket'
object_pattern = 'test_delete\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\/alpha\/data-1-2123-[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.json'

array_objects = []

with airflow.DAG(
        'test_delete_dag',
        start_date=datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1),
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    
     def get_and_delete_obj():
         hook = GCSHook()
         objects = hook.list(bucket_name=bucket_name)
         
         for obj in objects:
                if re.match(object_pattern,obj):
                    array_objects.append(obj)
         print(array_objects)
        
         for arr in array_objects:
                hook.delete(bucket_name=bucket_name, object_name=arr)

     test_delete = python.PythonOperator(
            task_id='delete_gcs_obj',
            provide_context=True,
            python_callable=get_and_delete_obj,
            )

     test_delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Airflow specification.
I am not sure if it supports wildcards like '*'.

```
class GCSDeleteObjectsOperator(BaseOperator):
    """
    Deletes objects from a Google Cloud Storage bucket, either
    from an explicit list of object names or all objects
    matching a prefix.
    :param bucket_name: The GCS bucket to delete from
    :param objects: List of objects to delete. These should be the names
        of objects in the bucket, not including gs://bucket/
    :param prefix: Prefix of objects to delete. All objects matching this
        prefix in the bucket will be deleted.
```